# image on radio button is not working

Tags: html, css, image, radio-button

I am using an `image` for `radio buttons` but it's `not working`. Please help me guys.

**Here is my Html**

```
<div class="redio-box"> 
    <input name="sms_notification" class="radio" type="radio" value="1" checked>
      <label for="subscribe">
        <span></span>
        Subscribe
      </label> 
    <input name="sms_notification" class="radio" type="radio" value="0" >
      <label for="unsubscribe">
        <span></span>
        Unsubscribe
      </label>
</div>
```

**Here is my Css**

```
.redio-box .radio {
    display:none; *display:inline; background:none;  width:auto;
}
.redio-box .radio + label { display:inline; font-size:12px; color:#C3B496; }
.redio-box .radio + label span {
    display:inline-block; *display:none;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:-2px 2px 0 4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../../images/check_radio_sheet.png) -30px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.redio-box .radio:checked + label span {
    background:url(../../images/check_radio_sheet.png) -45px top no-repeat;
}
```

**and here is the [image](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZivCP6hA_1UyfTlzNFdfmZfeGoPUO1EajrdtU5J4aFSFDtqUHsI_1tknP71lxAVQTCBk2i051n-zvxp9Z8k4HAXvoIZYu4gAasy02uBjE2eMkLkFZShKgCaSmo1da3Gz31NqYGAkH0F6Z59kBJrBd5uoXYkXpBimDE9eHHGEq6tn9CfGugXGQDp-8iMY40DbJ4KtMuJcIU-OwVQulkzyP2Y_1rg-6yZuDTWsrOlwmkY1zX5_1Pumzeqa_1ObwbyqeSUvbrdtuvAavtFVR7WkqOFKNFm79VEk40Xy58W9-2U5lfQOUE3FUeHV9amXavJBRamqpIElKVENLJfOKyw_1jXwJjEn8blL7YPVUp7A0HOPu23p_1BqWUuA4zHyaANP5dw1Kyq_1hVI7Ce37T02AVUYKi2i5ri_1yRHItrX8MzgkhexS_1ooDN8YU4KmGahsAYTy1jmZfsoQiARY48rSZ1RkNE49cUxvKhQF3Yrhl5hmLZDSuckQpI4oF_16unHyJp1WwaRPYPA2r4U_1vos-_13XzHc3EAmWx_1e0YnndadNah9yQZpo4auZJjfnvoYQurtcCmD44-DcRWE2Nyw67LqBWtepmDfW-65BX6Xyf-zGAkYfzrs1tgOp4YvyRCznNmBEhHushNIl7oHwvo7DGu-5vQu5GJ3EmJgZn-zWUIcPgJz6HIh2wlUPJPC2pQhCZY-_144utW2hOpvgME1MCyancksj5KEA64Y785OFs43-zKRiO28jPUfLaYr5HruIJsE4oZLw3kOBt_1t0RzclcqitDLBRuCeZMB6t033p-fdFlUr0D7jcSaaLzBYO2VRpG-VNRO3xRIXZQ73E6SYIMo5gqn47_11i5HM8BhlFwF4bJi1YqvrJmaRRGxxHh_1aNFMjw-nqEWkZ8hqWWxWXKHg0YhR2b3JvJR_1CV7rMYjyOD_1s2oVVrvjChiutUYpwpcA)**

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with image?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of fiddles, just follow it, it's easy to understand and implement.

[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/10/)

[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Zgh24/1/)

[FIDDLE3](http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/GsSvF/)

[Very Good Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B63PH/)

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/awelaw/1/edit)

HTML :

```
<body>    
  <label class="fb" for="fb1">
    <input id="fb1" type="radio" name="fb" value="small" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>

  <label class="fb" for="fb2">
    <input id="fb2" type="radio" name="fb" value="big"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>

  <label class="fb" for="fb3">
    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="med" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>

  <label class="fb" for="fb4">
    <input id="fb4" type="radio" name="fb" value="long" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x15/35d/fff&text=f">
  </label>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.fb > input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + img{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img{
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: actually I want to use img with css can you help me to find out issue in my css

Comment: In 4th fiddle Image is used inside css as you want, what else you want ? Tell me, if I can help you.

Comment: answers should explain what to do - and how to solve the problem - not just "STRG-C" "STRG-V" some links :)

Comment: yes thats what I want to say I saw 4th fiddle but it was too complicated and not the solution of my question

Comment: Can You create fiddle for that problem, then I  ll try on it.Right now I am somewhat busy, so will you create fiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an issue with the css. This worked for me.

HTML:

```
<input name="sms_notification" class="radio" type="radio" value="1" checked>
    <label for="subscribe">
        <span></span> Subscribe
    </label> 
<input name="sms_notification" class="radio" type="radio" value="0" >
    <label for="unsubscribe">
        <span></span> Unsubscribe
    </label>
```

CSS:

```
.radio {
    display:none; *display:inline; background:none;  width:auto;
}
.radio + label { display:inline; font-size:12px; color:#C3B496; }
.radio + label span {
    display:inline-block; *display:none;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:-2px 2px 0 4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/tfumE8xhOyGr33JKe-Wk5TJKNIOt_qaPW5rDKIhvjAis9qmlsgc91Devz0RoHodZoim-jg=s56") -30px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.radio:checked + label span {
    background:url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/tfumE8xhOyGr33JKe-Wk5TJKNIOt_qaPW5rDKIhvjAis9qmlsgc91Devz0RoHodZoim-jg=s56") -45px top no-repeat;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LNcN8/)

Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it look [**custom**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/custom%20-%20Copy.html).
you will need to add the `::after` and `::before` psuedo classes to the label.

I have encased the radio button and the corresponding label in `span`;

```
<span class="custom-checkbox ">
  <input id="rb1" type="radio" name="r" class="kd-radio ">
  <label for="rb1" class="kd-radio-label">Male</label>
</span>
```

Check here for [***live demo***](http://jsbin.com/icEKaBu/1/)

Comment: Sorry I did not get what do you mean? Can you please show me your code.thanks

Comment: yes your answer is working but can you show me your css code thanks

Comment: http://jsbin.com/icEKaBu/1/edit?html,css,output , @user3110655, this is your code.

Comment: it's so much css in your code.Can I get an easy way Please.Please try to find problem with my code. That will be great help

Comment: @user3110655, try to find the relevant code in the answer, not the jsbin, And right click on the element and click inspect element.

Comment: you are doing this using any other method not the background url as I used.Actually I want to use <span> background url.

Comment: You will have to use the image url in the "after" css, I don't think making a css statement of background url will apply the image.